# Error installing Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, nuget, nuget-package

Trying to install `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` version 1.1.3, but keep getting the error

> Unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common'.
>   Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
>   Packages'

My current project is from the Azure QnA bot template

Any help with this would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error installing Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table NuGet

This is a [known issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/385), if project is configured to use `packages.config` this issue will manifest itself.

And this issue is fixed for `PackageReference`. NuGet team are determining if needs to fix this for `packages.config`, or leave it as is.

Before add nuget package, go to `Tools`-`Options`->`NuGet Package Manager`->`General`, change the default package management format to `PackageReference`. Then restart the Visual Studio, reload your project, add that package.

If you still get the same error, please check following [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-sdk-dotnet#troubleshooting):

> - Use Package Manage Console to install the    Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table package and its dependencies. To do
>     this, type the following in the Package Manager Console for your
>     solution.
>
>   `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table -IncludePrerelease`
> - Using your preferred Nuget package management tool, install the    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common Nuget package before installing
>     Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table.

Hope this helps.